# Express a number using words in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I heard that we can use the English words to express the number in Mathematica. Like using *One hundred* to express 100. Which function can do it?

Comment: Do you mean how to read words and get a number, or take the number and generate the words?

Answer (score 5):

A solution basically equivalent to dreeves's solution (but [not available at the time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematica#Version_history) of his answer) would be to call [`WolframAlpha[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WolframAlpha.html) directly from Mathematica (this requires an internet connection).  For example,

```
WolframAlpha["6 million 2 hundred and 12 thousand and fifty two", 
             {{"Input", 1}, "Plaintext"}]
```

returns the string

```
"6212052"
```

So we can construct the following function that returns the actual number

```
textToNumber[num_String] := 
 Module[{in = WolframAlpha[num, {{"Input", 1}, "Plaintext"}]},
  If[StringMatchQ[in, NumberString], ToExpression[in], $Failed]]
```

It also works with decimals and negative numbers, e.g., `textToNumber["minus one point one"]`.

Note that we could ask for things other than `"Plaintext"` output. The easiest way to find out what's available is to enter some number, eg,`WolframAlpha["twelve"]`, and explore the options available when you press the ⨁ signs on the right of each "pod". It is also worth exploring the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WolframAlpha.html), where you find useful output "formats" such as `"MathematicaParse"` and `"PodIDs"`.

We can also go in the other direction:

```
numberToText[num_Integer] := WolframAlpha[ToString[num], 
                               {{"NumberName", 1}, "Plaintext"}]
```

I couldn't find the right incantations to get the spoken phrase form for non-integers. If someone knows the right spell, or if [W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) gains this ability, please feel free to update this answer. It's a shame that [`SpokenString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SpokenString.html) does not have an option for reading numbers as their spoken phrases.

Comment: The problem with all the W|A based solutions is that there's a limited number of calls to W|A allowed, per day. So, it's not really a good automated method. I had a method I used for some application a while back, I'm going to see if I can dig it up.

Comment: @Eli: True, I never intended the solutions for more than occasional use. Is your method for going the easy way - numbers to text - or vice versa? Numbers to text can be solved with a dictionary and recursion. The reverse needs to be a lot more flexible, with some clever string patterns etc...

Answer (score 2):

I see that Wolfram Alpha can do that, so here's a kludgy little function that sends the English string to Wolfram Alpha and parses the result:

```
w2n[s_String] := ToExpression[StringCases[
  Import["http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=" <> StringReplace[s, " "->"+"],
        "String"], 
  RegularExpression["Hold\\[([^\\]]*)\\]"] -> "$1"][[1]]]
```

Example:

```
w2n["two million six hundred sixty-six"]

> 2000666
```

Does Wolfram Alpha provide an actual API?  That would be really great!

PS: They have one now but it's expensive: http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/

PPS: I notice that the wolframalpha results page changed a bit and my scraping no longer works.  Some variant on that regular expression should work though.

Comment: I should probably do an actual url_encode instead of just replacing spaces with pluses, but for numbers in English that seems to suffice.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code:

```
IntegerName[78372112345]
```

This is the output:

> **78 billion 372 million 112 thousand 345**

Answer (score 0):

not available back in '09...

```
SemanticInterpretation["one hundred fifty thousand three hunded and six"]
```

or

```
Interpreter["SemanticNumber"]["one hundred fifty thousand three hunded and six"]
```

> 150306

( notice my spelling error didn't phase it..)

The two functions are not the same by the way,

```
SemanticInterpretation["six and forty two thousandths"]//N  (* 6.042 *)
Interpreter["SemanticNumber"]["six and forty two thousandths"] (*fails*)
```